# JMSSerializerBundle is returning doubles as strings in JSON

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

So we're using the `JMSSerializerBundle` in our Symfony2 project to generate some JSON for our clients. It's serializing our Doctrine2 entities and works like charm, with one exception. All doubles/decimal values are strings in the resulting JSON and this is confusing the clients.

Our serialized entity looks like this, I've only pasted the relevant attributes/getters here.

```
class Offer
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @var double $latitude
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=7)
     * @Groups("offerlist")
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var double $longitude
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=7)
     * @Groups("offerlist")
     */
    private $longitude;

    [...]

    /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return double
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Get longitude
     *
     * @return double
     */
    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    [...]
}
```

The latitude/longitude values show up in the JSON like this:

```
{
    "latitude" : "5.3452",
    "longitude" : "54.2312"
}
```

How do I get rid of the quotes, so it's a number in the JSON and not a string? This should be really easy, but I can't find anything in the [docs](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/reference/annotations) or online about this problem. Hope someone can give me a hand here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your latitude and longitude columns are using Doctrine's decimal type, which is represented as a string.

You could use Doctrine's double type if you can:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="double")
 */
private $latitude;
```

or use JMSSerializerBundle's [`@Type` annotation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/reference/annotations#type):

```
/**
 * ...
 * @Serializer\Type("double")
 */
private $latitude;
```

Comment: maybe you can help me out on a similar issue ;)

i've already set the Type("double") annoataion, but i can't find a solution to get the serializer to add trailing zeros to those values.

I'd like the annotated fields to return 100.00 instead of 100, but couldn't find a proper place yet

Comment: 100 === 100.00 if it's a number, things like these are not supported unless you'll serialize the value as a string. I really can't imagine a case where it's required to send the zero's over. If it's about significance, you could send that in a separate value. I think many databases and programming languages will also ignore the .00 so even if you get it serialized that way it'll probably be lost on deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "double" as column type because you risk having malformed representation of the coordinates. Better cast your attribute:

```html
     /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return double
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return (double)$this->latitude;
    }
```